# Connot fetch google api token through when using gmailQuickStart

Tags: java, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I have download an gmail quick start demo from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java.

And I have already registed in google cloud platform, and enalbed the gmail api, created my own project and credentials...

When I thoughout everthing is going on the right way. Next second, I'm stuck in trouble.

First time, I am runing the original program as the website provided.

```
    import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
    import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
    import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
    import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
    import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
    import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
    import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
    import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
    import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
    import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Label;
    import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListLabelsResponse;
    
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class GmailQuickstart {
        private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Gmail API Java Quickstart";
        private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
    
        /**
         * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
         * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
         */
        private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);
        private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";
    
        /**
         * Creates an authorized Credential object.
         * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
         * @return An authorized Credential object.
         * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
         */
        private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
            // Load client secrets.
            InputStream in = GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
            if (in == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
            }
            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
    
            // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .build();
            LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
            return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
        }
    
        public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
            // Build a new authorized API client service.
            final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();
    
            // Print the labels in the user's account.
            String user = "me";
            ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
            List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
            if (labels.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No labels found.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Labels:");
                for (Label label : labels) {
                    System.out.printf("- %s\n", label.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the dependencies as follow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
    
        <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmail.demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>gmail-demo</name>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <description>Gmail Demo</description>
    
        <properties>
            <parent.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</parent.version>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.30.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
                <version>1.31.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-gmail -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
                <version>v1-rev110-1.25.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
    </project>
```

then i have got

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:994)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1340)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1315)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:108)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:79)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:995)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:322)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:158)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:79)
        at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:127)
        at GmailQuickstart.getCredentials(GmailQuickstart.java:57)
        at GmailQuickstart.main(GmailQuickstart.java:63)
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
        ... 17 more
```

After my googling and googling, I find it might be a proxy problems. And then I rewrite the program as following, added proxy configs.

````
    import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
    import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
    import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
    import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.ConnectionFactory;
    import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
    import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
    import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
    import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
    import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
    import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
    import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Label;
    import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListLabelsResponse;
    
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    import java.net.Proxy;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class GmailQuickstart3 {
        private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Gmail API Java Quickstart";
        private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
    
        /**
         * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
         * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
         */
        private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);
        private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";
    
        /**
         * Creates an authorized Credential object.
         * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
         * @return An authorized Credential object.
         * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
         */
        private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
            // Load client secrets.
            InputStream in = GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
            if (in == null) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
            }
            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
    
            // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .build();
            LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
            return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
        }
    
        public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
            // Build a new authorized API client service.
            System.out.println(System.getProperties());
    
            final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT =
                    (new NetHttpTransport.Builder())
                            .trustCertificates(GoogleUtils.getCertificateTrustStore())
                            .setProxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("******", 30900)))
    //                         .setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
                            .build();
            Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT)).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    
            // Print the labels in the user's account.
            String user = "me";
            ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
            List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
            if (labels.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No labels found.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Labels:");
                for (Label label : labels) {
                    System.out.printf("- %s\n", label.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ```
    Then I have got
    ```
    Please open the following address in your browser:
      https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=2467719584-um6onu5chc8hmn00is5j3ctl6g2mvvru.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels
    Attempting to open that address in the default browser now...
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.doTunneling(HttpURLConnection.java:2152)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:183)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1340)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1315)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:108)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:79)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:995)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:322)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:158)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:79)
        at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:127)
        at GmailQuickstart3.getCredentials(GmailQuickstart3.java:63)
        at GmailQuickstart3.main(GmailQuickstart3.java:88)
````

```
CONNECT oauth2.googleapis.com:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_231
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-length: 0
Location: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/
```

Can anyone helps me going throught it?
I am really confused, the problems have been a few days, and I haven't found any useful document.

gradle runing result:（Added at 9 Oct 2020）

```
PS D:\xnj\workspace\gmailQuickstart> gradle run

> Task :run
十月 09, 2020 11:07:16 下午 com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
警告: unable to change permissions for everybody: D:\xnj\workspace\gmailQuickstart\tokens IDLE
十月 09, 2020 11:07:16 下午 com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory setPermissionsToOwnerOnly
警告: unable to change permissions for owner: D:\xnj\workspace\gmailQuickstart\tokens
2020-10-09 23:07:16.074:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2020-10-09 23:07:16.075:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
2020-10-09 23:07:16.088:INFO::Started SocketConnector@localhost:8888
Please open the following address in your browser:
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=2467719584-um6onu5chc8hmn00is5j3ctl6g2mvvru.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels
Attempting to open that address in the default browser now...
2020-10-09 23:08:54.694:INFO::Stopped SocketConnector@localhost:8888
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
        at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:158)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:79)
        at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:84)
        at GmailQuickstart.getCredentials(GmailQuickstart.java:57)
        at GmailQuickstart.main(GmailQuickstart.java:63)

> Task :run FAILED
```

Before I click the url in console, the console's log will pending at 'Attempting to open that address in the default browser now...', it will stay as it is, if I do nothing. And when I clicked the url, the console will immediately print the error trace and tell me that the Socket 'connect timed out'

[timeout-picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnmKK.png)

Comment: Please open the following address in your browser:  <--what happends if you place that link into a normal browser window.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, the quickstart is working just fine. So you tried accessing the provided URL through your browser? What happened then?

Comment: Yeah，I have accessed the provided link，and it let me choose a google account, I just do so. And I got: Received verification code. You may now close this window.                        The broswer url changes to http://localhost:8888/Callback?code=4%2F5AHlk0MZxfhy0qUgOX1cTVCSh2IImbui3QrvYk105EvMCEf9um-OmU3pzFvLnREVGVu0RWhO30_oGur-UWdFlCU&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.labels

Comment: Are you following the quickstart as it is? Using gradle, etc. Can you try opening the URL with a different browser? Do you notice any change?

Comment: A moment before, I used gradle to run this this program, but it still failed. Log is append above, please look at       "gradle runing result"

Comment: I have used chrome and firefox browsers to open the url, the result is the same: connect timed out.

Comment: Please make sure you follow every single step of the quickstart as it is explained and in the same order. That includes the creation of the different directories, initializing the project with `gradle init`, setting the right dependencies, etc.: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java#step_2_prepare_the_project